# SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.Error

Tags: maven, apache-spark, jar, pom.xml, oozie-workflow

Hi i have multiple SLF4J bindings error when i schedule my spark job in ozzie. some of these bindings are part of the cache diretcory. how do i resolve. Please find the error message below.

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/scratch/yarn6/filecache/22006/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.8.2.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/scratch/yarn6/filecache/21799/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.25.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-6.3.3-1.cdh6.3.3.p0.1796617/jars/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.25.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
```

PLease help me to resolve this .

Comment: can you share your pom xml ? or you can check dependency tree and see if some dependency brings different version of slf4j.